# Why are my questions being closed when others are not?

Tags: discussion

EnergyNumbers, who has only made 1 original contribution to this site apart from hundreds of close votes, and possibly others have voted to close a few of my questions for being too basic.

This is fine, but I consider this bullying when they are singling out my questions, rather than looking at all the questions on the site.  I have found countless simple questions that are much simpler than many of the questions I have asked, but have not had a single comment on them by EnergyNumbers or a single close vote.  Here are some examples of some really simple questions that haven't been voted on to close.

*(Note since initially asking this question, these questions have now accumulated close votes also)*

[How long does it take for the ocean conveyor to circulate?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-long-does-it-ocean-conveyor-take-to-circulate)

[What are the differences between geology, petrology, and lithology?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/281/what-are-the-differences-between-geology-petrology-and-lithology) (esp compare to my [geophysics vs geology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-geologist-and-a-geophysicist) question instantly closed)

[What is a good definition of the word "rock" for teaching?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/349/what-is-a-good-definition-of-the-word-rock-for-teaching)

[What's the difference between the upper & lower mantle?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/335/whats-the-difference-between-the-upper-lower-mantle)

[Why do crystals, like quartz and diamonds, form in different colors?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/322/why-do-crystals-like-quartz-and-diamonds-form-in-different-colors)

*(Note many of the following questions have been re-opened since this post was created.)*
In my opinion many of the above questions are simpler or at least as simple as many of the questions of mine that have accumulated close votes such as [Is it true that a butterfly flapping its wings can result in a tornado in a distant location?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/245/is-it-true-that-a-butterfly-flapping-its-wings-can-result-in-a-tornado-in-a-dist) (8 upvotes), [Will the Earth ever stop rotating?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/236/will-the-earth-ever-stop-rotating) (7 upvotes), [What is the difference between a geologist and a geophysicist?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-geologist-and-a-geophysicist) (4 upvotes) and many others which I am not going to list.

While you may say that I am free to cast close votes on the questions I have listed, I personally think they should remain on the site.  My issue is that many of my questions that are either more complex or of equal complexity are being commented on by EnergyNumbers yet he neglects all of these other simple questions.  Why is she just picking on my questions?

I also have an issue with EnergyNumbers having only made 1 original contribution to the site, and spends most of his time trying to thwart the contributions of others.

Comment: Earlier today, I received a critical comment from this individual, and then three downvotes on different questions all in the same MINUTE. It could be coincidence of course (maybe there three downvoters at the same time).

Comment: @Mew the close voters after the initial are not mysterious, they are just looking at the review queues, which a question gets deposited into after the first close vote so others can quickly take a look and evaluate the merits of closing it or not.

Comment: @Mew its not just your questions in the review queue with his comment attached to it, he's hitting every Q he feels is non-expert and it does not appear you are being singled out.

Comment: @Mew if you feel that way, vote to close them to bring them to the attention of the community at large (via the close queue).

Comment: @Mew that is fine for a launched site and the later stages of public beta, but now is the time to fill the site with expert-level content to draw in experts during the initial part of public beta.  The experts don't get driven away by basic questions, they get driven away when thats all there is to see.  Focus on expert level stuff, someone will eventually get around to asking the easy stuff as the site grows.

Comment: @casey, my belief is that experts are drawn in by interesting questions in their field, whether basic or not.  What expert will want to solve other very hard problems in their spare time.  Experts will initially prefer interesting questions in their spare time, than tedious technical questions.  Experts often enjoy helping those with the fundamental basic questions in their field even more so than answering technical questions that their peers struggle with.

Comment: @Mew I'll gladly spend an hour or two taking a crack at  a hard question before I spend 5 minutes to answer the easy ones.  The interesting ones *are* the hard ones, not the other way around.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes on many of the questions you linked to, I don't think this is a case of bullying (all of the other questions you linked to also have close votes). I think the bullying accusation, founded or not, has rather derailed the valuable point of this question, which is why there are so many basic question being closed. There is a cleaner discussion of this point at http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/34/level-of-the-questions-so-far/48#48

Answer (score 13):

There's a large difference between bullying and close votes.

Closing on Stack Exchange is meant to identify questions that aren't on-topic or *can be made better so they're answerable*.

Closing isn't a personal attack against you.

Stack Exchange is supposed to be a place where experts get together to answer questions. Apparently that user doesn't think that those questions are expert level. **That's not an abuse of the system.** We're in private beta right now to *identify who we are and what is acceptable to ask here.* People are free to vote how they choose, and remember, *5 people* need to agree to close your question.

I'd also suggest you read this Meta Stack Exchange post: [What is the purpose of closing a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213382/what-is-the-purpose-of-closing-a-question). An answer from that states:

> The purpose of closing a question is to prevent answers from being posted **while the problems with the question are fixed (a process I call "rehabilitation").** Without closing, there's no motivation for a user to improve their question.

Now, the problem identified here is that (possibly) your questions aren't expert level. *So edit them to make them better!*

Please don't take this as bullying. The people close voting here are **only trying to make the site better and make sure it succeeds, and aren't trying to attack you.**

Comment: @Mew ... they either a) haven't seen those questions, or b) don't think those questions are simple.

Comment: It's not bullying, @Mew. It's how these sites work. hichris123 is editing your title to be more constructive, and I (and the system) support that.

Comment: @Mew: I disagree with the close votes, but *all* of those questions you linked to have close votes, not just yours.

Comment: @mew: well, no-one can be everywhere at once. You are asking a lot of basic-level questions (as are a few other people). If I was trying to close lots of basic questions, going to people's accounts and checking all the questions they've asked would probably be the quickest way. Not saying it's fair, but I don't think it's about *you*, it's about the questions (as evidenced by the fact that 3/5 of your top questions have no close votes).

Comment: @Mew And what do you mean by "they seem to be closed within a few hours of him voteing"... that just means that the community agrees with him. There's no problem wanting to moderate but not answer.